# What happens to a promise that's abandoned?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, promisekit

I have the following code defined in a view controller.

```
    _ = accountService.getAccount()

      .then { user -> Void in

         self.txtBxUser.text = user.username
         self.txtBxEmail.text = user.email
   }
```

`getAccount` makes a REST API request.

If the user dismisses the view controller before the call has returned, what happens to the call back chain? Does it still run given that, I presume, it's still referenced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the user dismisses the view controller before the call has returned, what happens to the call back chain? Does it still run given that, I presume, it's still referenced?

Yes, it does still run.

Be forewarned that the reference to `self` in the closure means that it is also keeping a reference to the view controller until that `then` closure finishes running. For that reason, if there's a chance the view controller could have been dismissed, you might want to use a `weak` reference:

```
_ = accountService.getAccount().then { [weak self] user -> Void in
    self?.txtBxUser.text = user.username
    self?.txtBxEmail.text = user.email
}
```

Ideally, you should also make `getAccount` cancellable and cancel it in the view controller's `deinit`.

(Note, in [FAQ - Should I be Concerned About Retain Cycles](http://promisekit.org/faq/#should-i-be-concerned-about-retain-cycles), the PromiseKit documentation points out that you don't need `weak` references, which is correct. It's just a question of whether or not you mind if the deallocation of the dismissed view controller is deferred until after the promise is fulfilled.)

Answer (score 2):

> Should I be concerned about retain cycles? tl;dr: it’s safe to use
>   self in promise handlers.
>
> This is safe:
>
> ```
> somePromise.then {
>     self.doSomething()
> }
> ```
>
> Provided somePromise resolves, the function passed to then will be
>   released, thus specifying `[weak self]` is not necessary.
>
> Specifying `[unowned self]` is likely dangerous.
>
> You’re telling me not to worry about retain cycles?! No, it’s just
>   that by default you are not going to cause retain cycles when using
>   PromiseKit. But it is still possible, for example:
>
> ```
> self.handler = {
>     self.doSomething
>     self.doSomethingElse }
> somePromise.then(execute: self.handler)
> ```
>
> The closure we assign to
>   `handler` strongly retains `self`. `handler` is strongly retained by `self`.
>   It’s a typical retain cycle. Don’t write typical retain cycles!
>
> Notably, this is not a retain cycle:
>
> ```
>  somePromise.then(execute: self.doSomething).then(execute: self.doSomethingElse)
> ```

[source](http://promisekit.org/faq/)